# AWS EC2 - Cucumber, Selenium-Webdriver, Capybara, Ruby, **Jenkins** - Not a File "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, ruby, capybara, aws

I was hoping to get a web automation test script working on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Ruby; Capybara and Cucumber frameworks.

I am intending to use Selenium-Webdriver as my web-driver (as opposed to waitr) and have also included Google's Chromedriver **(Downloaded and extracted to the  `/usr/bin/` directory. and added to the server's `$PATH` variable.)**

I am also intending to run this headlessly via Jenkins (as this is an AWS virtual server, it does not have any kind of GUI)

I am including the code being used. **Please Note:** I am attempting this in Ruby, but not rails!

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << File.expand_path(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'lib'))
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

if ENV['IN_BROWSER']
  # On demand: non-headless tests via Selenium/WebDriver
  # To run the scenarios in browser (default: Firefox), use the following command line:
  # IN_BROWSER=true bundle exec cucumber
  # or (to have a pause of 1 second between each step):
  # IN_BROWSER=true PAUSE=1 bundle exec cucumber
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1800, 1000)

  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    require 'selenium/webdriver'
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
    profile['browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force'] = false
    profile['browser.cache.disk.enable'] = false
    profile['browser.cache.memory.enable'] = false
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 240 # instead of the default 60
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :profile => profile, http_client: client)

  end
else
  ...
```

When attempting to run this through Jenkins, I get the following error message:

```
not a file: "/usr/bin/chromedriver" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:145:in `assert_file'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:150:in `assert_executable'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:46:in `executable_path='
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/features/support/env.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:253:in `load_step_definitions'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:61:in `run!'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/var/jenkins_home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I've not figured out why Jenkins is throwing up this message (I haven't even gotten to the part about the actual display (Which I'm using Xvfb to imitate a screen)) Can you help?

Comment: Have you check this error " not a file: "/usr/bin/chromedriver" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError) "                                  May be you have not put chromedriver there

Comment: @Sagar007 - Hmm. Now let me think... `(Downloaded and extracted to the  /usr/bin/ directory. and added to the server's $PATH variable.)` - My original post - I think I have, but then; I could be in the Matrix

Comment: Sorry if that sounded sarcastic, but I don't tolerate fools gladly. It's one thing to ask a question; it's another to ask one that has already been answered and all you needed to do was read.

Comment: Sorry but sometimes very small mistakes can be happen by any person. We all do not know all the answer but new approach can help.

Comment: @Sagar007 - True enough.

Comment: I have upvote your question. It might help you to get right answer.

Comment: @Sagar007 - Thanks; but I've figured it out on my own, so I'll self-answer for anyone else having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I really was stuck and I couldn't figure it out; so I decided to try something different.

I disabled the docker image holding my Jenkins instance and instead loaded up my Apache2 Web server and installed Jenkins via:

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

This immediately set up jenkins with a user on the AWS Ubuntu install.

I found out that, while on Docker, the Jenkins had not set up its user properly and so; when it came to looking for the binary files for chromedriver it was attempting to look at files it had no right looking in as it wasn't a registered user.

I could have probably edited Jenkins to use an appropriate user; but this worked just as well.